# CSS / Slider is off alignment

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, slider

Recently got evo-slider to work on wordpress. I have a custom bit of code that takes the featured image and loops it through the slider. However for some reason the slider is off alignment ([my website](http://www.angrycrows.com)). I'm not totally sure whats going on, but it might have something to do with the margin.

```
.evoslider.default {
position: relative;
width: 920px;
height: 320px;
margin: 0 auto;
border: 15px solid #fafafa;
padding: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
background: #d3d3d3;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
```

if I remove the margin it will fix the alignment issue with inside of the slider, but it will be off margin.

Answer (score 0):

Because your container has a fixed width (920px), you could do something like that:

```
top: 0;
left: 50%;
margin: 0 0 0 -460px; // -(920px / 2)
```

And you don't need the "padding-right: 5px;" because that's already included in the previous line.